Fragment is not loading
Im trying to implement Room but when the app is opened a progress bar is coming and the fragment is not starting .
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val listFragment = ListFragment()
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
        replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, listFragment)
            .commit()
    }
}



I think you are missing a lot of things, before using ListFragment, try to read the documentation. You must implement an Adapter for this. Check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment

can u share xml code of you activity to verify that you have implemented it in a correct way
